# sum numbers cubed equal to 100

Tags: java, arrays

the sum of three numbers cubed is 100. Which are those numbers? the numbers can be negative or positive. I try to do it, but the program executes very slowly

```
package numeros;

public class Numeros {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double resultado = 0;
        for (int i = -2000; i <= 2000; i++) {
            for (int j = -2000; j <= 2000; j++) {

                for (int k = -2000; k <= 2000; k++) {
                    resultado=Math.pow(i, 3)+ Math.pow(j,3) + Math.pow(k,3);
                    if(resultado==100){
                        System.out.println(i+" "+j+" "+k);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you start from `-2000`?

Comment: You can simply calculate the cubed sums and you've effectively created the endlessly-solved-already "subset sum" problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Comment: *"I try to do it, but the program executes very slowly ..."* - Yes. 4000 * 4000 * 4000 * 3 * time to run `Math.pow` is a long time.

Comment: How much time do you expect to achieve 192 billion pow operations, 128 billion additions, 64 billion comparisons and 64 billion conditional branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a little bit optimized version, which runs about 1-2 seconds on my desktop:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    for (long i = -2000; i <= 2000; i++) {
        final long pi = i * i * i;
        if ((i > 0) && (pi > 100)) {
            break;
        }
        for (long j = i; j <= 2000; j++) {
            final long pj = pi + (j * j * j);
            if ((j > 0) && (pj > 100)) {
                break;
            }
            for (long k = j; k <= 2000; k++) {
                final long pk = pj + (k * k * k);
                if ((k > 0) && (pk > 100)) {
                    break;
                }

                if (pk == 100) {
                    System.out.println(i + " " + j + " " + k);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

output is:

```
-1797 -903 1870
-161 -139 190
-6 -3 7
```

Comment: Nice optimization. You must have a powerful desktop though. Out of curiosity, can you share the solution?

Comment: btw, are you sure about your `break` when `pi > 100` ?

Comment: @A.S.H yes, if i>0 then j>0 and k>0, so final sum definitely > 100

Comment: ah ok, i just saw that you start from `j=i` and `k=j`. Still curious to know the solution, is there a solution in this range for `i^3 + j^3 + k^3 = 100`?

Comment: @A.S.H what do you mean "know the solution"? check the wiki page posted in comments

Comment: I mean what did the `System.out.println(i + " " + j + " " + k)` print when you ran the program? Did it print anything, or `pk == 100` was never found?

Comment: Guys , what values can take  i,j and k  ? I choose  from -2000 to 2000

Comment: @rubystudent actually there is no final range for answer

Comment: but  what values would you choose?

Comment: @rubystudent `for (long i = -2000; i <= 2000; i++)`

Comment: Lashare Can I choose the range I want?

Comment: Lashare . Is there  another way of do it? My computer is not very fast

Comment: They other guys said to use subset sum., but I do not know how do that

Answer (score 1):

Here is an O(n<sup>2</sup>) algorithm.  It pre-computes all cubes and places them in a `HashMap`, with the cubes as keys (for O(1) lookup) and the bases as values.  The idea is to compute `sum` = i<sup>3</sup> + j<sup>3</sup> and to determine if the differences `100 - sum` or `sum - 100` exist as keys in the map.  It also computes `sum` = i<sup>3</sup> - j<sup>3</sup> and determines if these differences `100 - sum` or `sum - 100` exist as keys in the map.

```
public static void testCubes(int limit)
{
    Map<Long, Long> cubes = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < limit + 1; i++)
    {
        cubes.put((long) i * i * i, (long) i);
    }

    for (Map.Entry<Long, Long> e1 : cubes.entrySet())
    {
        long i = e1.getValue();
        for (Map.Entry<Long, Long> e2 : cubes.entrySet())
        {
            long j = e2.getValue();
            long sum = e1.getKey() + e2.getKey();
            long diff = 100 - sum;
            if (diff > 0 && cubes.containsKey(diff))
            {
                System.out.println("(" + i + ", " + j + ", " + cubes.get(diff) + ")");
            }
            else if (diff < 0 && cubes.containsKey(-diff))
            {
                System.out.println("(" + i + ", " + j + ", " + -cubes.get(-diff) + ")");
            }
            else if (diff == 0)
            {
                System.out.println("(" + i + ", " + j + ", 0)");
            }

            sum = e1.getKey() - e2.getKey();
            diff = 100 - sum;
            if (diff > 0 && cubes.containsKey(diff))
            {
                System.out.println("(" + i + ", " + -j + ", " + cubes.get(diff) + ")");
            }
            else if (diff < 0 && cubes.containsKey(-diff))
            {
                System.out.println("(" + i + ", " + -j + ", " + -cubes.get(-diff) + ")");
            }
            else if (diff == 0)
            {
                System.out.println("(" + i + ", " + j + ", 0)");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Calling `testCubes(2000)` yields sub-second results on my PC.  Duplicates exist based on ordering.

```
(7, -3, -6)
(7, -6, -3)
(1870, -1797, -903)
(1870, -903, -1797)
(190, -139, -161)
(190, -161, -139)
```